# How to set to 100% and reset to 0% progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to work my progress bar to certain percentage on each click. Now its is working only up to 75%. On saving it should show 100% but it doesn't showing that.
Similarly by clicking back button it is going upto 25% on it should reset to 0% on clicking back button third time.

HTML

```
<div id="myProgressbar" class="progress" style="height: 2px;">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%; height: 10px;">
        <span class="sr-only">0% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btns">
    <button type="button" name="sub" id="back" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onclick="myFunctions()">back</button>
    <button type="button" name="add" id="continue" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="myFunction()" >Continue</button>
</div>

 <form action="/action_page.php" id="person" class="form-inline">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fname">First Name:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" required="" title="First Name"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mname">Middle Name:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="mname" placeholder="Middle Name" title="Middle Name"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lname">Last name:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" title="Last Name"></label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

</form> 

<form action="/action_page.php" id="details" class="form-inline">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address">Address:<input type="text" class="form-control"  rows="5" id="address" placeholder="Enter Address" title="Address"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="city">City:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="Enter City"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pin">Pin Code:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="pin" placeholder="Enter Pincode"></label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

</form> 

<form action="/action_page.php" id="account" class="form-inline">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pis">PIS:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="pis" placeholder="PIS"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="psp">PSP:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="psp" placeholder="PSP"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ped">PED:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ped" placeholder="PED"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pno">PNO:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="pno" placeholder="PNO"></label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

</form> 

<form action="/action_page.php" id="premium" class="form-inline">

     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pis">IPU:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="pis" placeholder="PIS"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="psp">NCB:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="psp" placeholder="PSP"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ped">TP REF:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ped" placeholder="PED"></label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

</form>  
<div class="btns">
    <button type="button" name="sub" id="back" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onclick="myFunctions()">back</button>
    <button type="button" name="add" id="continue" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="myFunction()" >Continue</button>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    var num = 1;
        document.getElementById("back").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("details").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("person").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("account").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("premium").style.display="none";


    function myFunction() {
        var listArry = document.getElementsByClassName('list');
        for(var i = 0; i < listArry.length; i++){
            listArry[i].style.color = "#CCC";
        }

        if (num==1){
            document.getElementById('navlnk1').style.color = "black";
            document.getElementById('navlnk').style.color = "#CCC";
            document.getElementById("back").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("person").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("details").style.display="block";
            var elem = document.getElementById("myProgressbar");   
            var width = 10;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
            function frame() {
                if (width >= 25) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                } else {
                width++; 
                document.getElementById("myProgressbar").style.backgroundColor = "#0FA561";
                elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
                elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
                    }
                }

            num=2;
        }

        else if(num==2){
            document.getElementById('navlnk2').style.color = "black";
            document.getElementById("details").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("account").style.display="block";
            var elem = document.getElementById("myProgressbar");   
            var width = 10;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
            function frame() {
                if (width >= 50) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                } else {
                width++; 
                elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
                elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
                }
            }

            num=3;
        }

        else if(num==3){
            document.getElementById('navlnk3').style.color = "black";
            document.getElementById("account").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("premium").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById('continue').innerHTML = "Save";
            var elem = document.getElementById("myProgressbar");   
            var width = 10;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
            function frame() {
                if (width >= 75) {
                clearInterval(id);
                } else {
                width++; 
                elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
                elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<script>
    var num = 1;
    function myFunctions() {
    var listArry = document.getElementsByClassName('list');
    for(var i = listArry.length; i >0;  i--){
    }
    if (num==3){
        document.getElementById('navlnk2').style.color = "black";
        document.getElementById('navlnk3').style.color = "#CCC";
        document.getElementById('navlnk1').style.color = "#CCC";
        document.getElementById('navlnk').style.color = "#CCC";
        document.getElementById("premium").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("account").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById('continue').innerHTML = "Continue";
        var elem = document.getElementById("myProgressbar");   
            var width = 10;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
            function frame() {
                if (width >= 50) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                } else {
                width++; 
                document.getElementById("myProgressbar").style.backgroundColor = "#0FA561";
                elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
                elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
                    }
                }
        num=2;

    }
    else if (num==2){
        document.getElementById('navlnk1').style.color = "black";
        document.getElementById('navlnk').style.color = "#CCC";
        document.getElementById('navlnk2').style.color = "#CCC";
        document.getElementById("account").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("details").style.display="block";
        var elem = document.getElementById("myProgressbar");   
            var width = 10;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
            function frame() {
                if (width >= 25) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                } else {
                width++; 
                document.getElementById("myProgressbar").style.backgroundColor = "#0FA561";
                elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
                elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
                    }
                }
        num=1;

    }
    else if(num==1){
        document.getElementById('navlnk').style.color = "black";
        document.getElementById('navlnk1').style.color = "#CCC";
        document.getElementById("details").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("person").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("back").disabled = true;

    }

    }
</script>

<script>
    var num = 1;
    function myFunctions() {
    var listArry = document.getElementsByClassName('list');
    for(var i = listArry.length; i >0;  i--){
    }
    if (num==3){
        document.getElementById('navlnk2').style.color = "black";
        document.getElementById('navlnk3').style.color = "#CCC";
        document.getElementById('navlnk1').style.color = "#CCC";
        document.getElementById('navlnk').style.color = "#CCC";
        document.getElementById("premium").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("account").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById('continue').innerHTML = "Continue";
        var elem = document.getElementById("myProgressbar");   
            var width = 10;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
            function frame() {
                if (width >= 50) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                } else {
                width++; 
                document.getElementById("myProgressbar").style.backgroundColor = "#0FA561";
                elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
                elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
                    }
                }
        num=2;

    }
    else if (num==2){
        document.getElementById('navlnk1').style.color = "black";
        document.getElementById('navlnk').style.color = "#CCC";
        document.getElementById('navlnk2').style.color = "#CCC";
        document.getElementById("account").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("details").style.display="block";
        var elem = document.getElementById("myProgressbar");   
            var width = 10;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
            function frame() {
                if (width >= 25) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                } else {
                width++; 
                document.getElementById("myProgressbar").style.backgroundColor = "#0FA561";
                elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
                elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
                    }
                }
        num=1;

    }
    else if(num==1){
        document.getElementById('navlnk').style.color = "black";
        document.getElementById('navlnk1').style.color = "#CCC";
        document.getElementById("details").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("person").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("back").disabled = true;

    }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can please post your full code , so i can help ...

Comment: Can you clean your code? remove duplicate or meaningless code -- many `document.getElementById(...)` statement result in `null`, and there are 2 `myFunctions` here.

Comment: Added complete code @ Anuj Tiwary

Comment: Sir may i know which one is meaning less code @  shaochuancs

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have tried workaround for your requirement... Please try it and let us know.

```js
var width = 40;
function move(data) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
 if(data == 'back' && width != 0){
     width = width-10; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }else if(data == 'continue' && width != 100){
     width = width+10; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
      
    }  
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 40%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move('back')">Back</button>
<button onclick="move('continue')">Continue</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this code is helpful for me but according to my program while onclicking it will call to another function. While calling this function from my function it showing soem errors

Comment: ok.what error you are getting? can you please paste it here so that we can understand your issue